# Does Notepad2 have a multiline mode for regex find/replace?

Tags: regex, notepad2

Completely rewriting this question since I've discovered the tru source of the problem.

I have the following text file:

```
strUpdateSql.Append(" this is a string ,")
 strUpdateSql.Append(" that has multiple lines ,")
    strUpdateSql.Append(" which need replacing,")
  strUpdateSql.Append(" with regex. ,")
strUpdateSql.Append(" I need multiline support. ,")
```

In .NET, I can use `^*.strUpdateSql.Append\("` regex multiline mode to remove all of the unwanted characters at the beginning of each line.  Notepad2, by default, doesn't recognize multiple lines, so it ends up removing almost the entire text.  I could craft my own harrowing regex string to look for newline characters, but I am looking for a simpler approach.  Newline mode would fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate ^ from your replacement string.

^ is a matching operator, not a replacing operator.

Matching operators goes only in the `Find with what` not in the `Replace with what`.

What goes in the `Replace with What` is text and possibly values found.

Comment: Are you talking about notepad++?

Comment: Still causes it to hang.  Did you actually try it?

Comment: No I didn't try it ... but now I did.  Works fine here.  Be sure to check the box for regular expressions.  Normally I use Notepad++ but previously used NP2.  And yes, I tested this in BOTH NP2 and NP++.

Comment: Hanging/crashing still.  What is the exact text you're using for each find/replace field?

Comment: ^ for find and " for replace, assuming what you want to do is simply replace start of line with quote.  BTW Notepad++ will correctly insert ^" as a replacement string while NP2 gets confused.  Another reason to upgrade.  Also you should report this bug to NP2 not here.

Comment: That's exactly what I am using.  Can anyone else try this?